# Getting div's side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the following pattern:

[image]

But so far I could get something like:

[image]

How do I somewhat get the Longtitude div to be beside the Latitude div?

```css
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 25%;
}

.lat label {
    display: block;
}

.long label {
    display: block;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "outer">
        <div class = "lat">
            <label>Latitude</label>
            <textarea id = "lat_text"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class = "long">
            <label>Longtitude</label>
            <textarea id = "long_text"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `flex` as display mode

Flexbox in detail:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
2. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
}

.lat {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.lat label {
    display: block;
}

.long label {
    display: block;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "outer">
        <div class = "lat">
            <label>Latitude</label>
            <textarea id = "lat_text"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class = "long">
            <label>Longtitude</label>
            <textarea id = "long_text"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use display flex on the outer box!

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to put the divs next to each other this should work.

```css
.div_1, .div_2{
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="div_1">
            <label>Latitude</label>
            <textarea id="lat_text"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="div_1">
            <label>Longtitude</label>
            <textarea id="long_text"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```